# CoreAudio right way to get layout configuration

Tags: macos, core-audio

In "Audio MIDI setup" application you can configure yours speakers setup, would it be multichannel(any configuration from 2.0 to 7.1) or stereo(only 2.0).

I'm trying to implement correct support of layout configuration in my application which is based on proprietary engine which by itself doesn't use coreaudio layout so i need to implement channel mapping by myself.

To get Multichannel configuration I'm using

```
AudioObjectPropertyAddress propertyAddress;
propertyAddress.mSelector = kAudioDevicePropertyPreferredChannelLayout;
propertyAddress.mScope = kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput;
propertyAddress.mElement = kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster;
```

Which works perfectly until configuration is selected to stereo **(!!!! not multichannel - stereo layout in it, but stereo as shown on image).**

[image]

In that case kAudioDevicePropertyPreferredChannelLayout property is still directing to multichannel configuration and i couldn't find any other property that i could use to determine which configuration is selected.

Can anybody help me with this situation?

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with stereo output, the output unit publishes a property `kAudioDevicePropertyPreferredChannelsForStereo` that you should use to determine the channel map.  This corresponds to the *Stereo* selection above.  As you've discovered, the `kAudioDevicePropertyPreferredChannelLayout` property refers to the *Multichannel* layout and should be used for non-stereo/mono audio.

Comment: Yap that one is easy. But question is how to determine if stereo or multichannel layout is selected?Also stereo channel mapping is applied by system and i do not need anything to do to map channels all is done by sytem.

Comment: I don't believe that the user selects one or the other to be active- the buttons are just the way Apple's way of simplifying the UI.  A device possesses both properties simultaneously.

Comment: Hmmmm. That one doesn't seems likely as after experimenting with configuration I did found that Preferred layout is remains 5.1 if that one is selected in multichannel even if stereo configuration is selected. And especially I'm surprised that channels mapping is made by system in case of stereo selection not by software it self (or one possible that all audio libraries which are used for audio output (used in flash and all other multi-platform frameworks )reacts correctly to channel mapping, but that do looks quite unlikely).

Comment: If i will select stereo with cross mapping L-2 R-1 and multichannel stereo without cross mapping L-1 R-2 any multi-platform application which doesn't work directly via CoreAudio is behaving differently (For example flash player in web browser) That one pushes me to decision that there is some trigger and definitely there is difference with which Stereo or Multichannel configuration is selected.

Comment: It's been my experience that which one is selected doesn't make a difference in playback.  Without code to test it's hard to say for certain.